# Issue with File.open in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am currently attempting to teach myself Ruby from the book, "Learning Ruby the Hard Way", and, as I was going through the exercises, I was told to run "ri File.open" and read some documentation.  After doing that, I have not been able to run File.open from any program.  Whenever I do so, I get this message:

```
Heres your file: ex15_sample.txt
= File.open

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File.open(filename, mode="r" [, opt])                 -> file
  File.open(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt])         -> file
  File.open(filename, mode="r" [, opt]) {|file| block } -> obj
  File.open(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt]) {|file| block } -> obj


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

With no associated block, File.open is a synonym for File.new. If the optional
code block is given, it will be passed the opened file as an argument, and the
File object will automatically be closed when the block terminates.  In this
instance, File.open returns the value of the block.

See IO.new for a list of values for the opt parameter.


Ill also ask you to type it again:
> ^Cex15.rb:13:in `gets': Interrupt
    from ex15.rb:13:in `<main>'

amelia@Amelia:~/Documents$ clear

amelia@Amelia:~/Documents$ ruby ex15.rb ex15_sample.txt
Here's your file: ex15_sample.txt
= File.open

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File.open(filename, mode="r" [, opt])                 -> file
  File.open(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt])         -> file
  File.open(filename, mode="r" [, opt]) {|file| block } -> obj
  File.open(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt]) {|file| block } -> obj


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

With no associated block, File.open is a synonym for File.new. If the optional
code block is given, it will be passed the opened file as an argument, and the
File object will automatically be closed when the block terminates.  In this
instance, File.open returns the value of the block.

See IO.new for a list of values for the opt parameter.


Ill also ask you to type it again:
> ex15_sample.txt
= File.open

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File.open(filename, mode="r" [, opt])                 -> file
  File.open(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt])         -> file
  File.open(filename, mode="r" [, opt]) {|file| block } -> obj
  File.open(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt]) {|file| block } -> obj


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

With no associated block, File.open is a synonym for File.new. If the optional
code block is given, it will be passed the opened file as an argument, and the
File object will automatically be closed when the block terminates.  In this
instance, File.open returns the value of the block.

See IO.new for a list of values for the opt parameter.
```

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

The program I am running is:

```
filename = ARGV.first

prompt = '> '

txt = File.open(filename)

puts"Here's your file: #{filename}"
puts txt.read()

puts "I'll also ask you to type it again:"
print prompt

file_again = STDIN.gets.chomp()

txt_again = File.open(file_again)

puts txt_again.read()
```

with ARGV.first being set to the a text file (specifically ex15_sample.txt for me)

Comment: Did you just use `File.open` with no parameters? That output is telling you that parameters are required. For example, `File.open('myfile.txt')` would open `myfile.txt`. If you Google "Ruby File.open examples" you'll find lots and lots of examples.

Comment: I've added the program I'm running to the question.

Comment: I have also added the exact results I get when running this program

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be stuck in ri.

Try pressing <kbd>CNTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to return to the shell prompt.

This happens if you enter `ri File.open` as two separate commands. The first `ri` opens ri in interactive mode and drops you into its command-line. `File.open` at that point displays help for any Ruby classes and methods you enter.

Regarding your code, you're using a bad practice for your `File.open`. Use a block with it to automatically close the file when the block exits. This is good housekeeping, and especially important when writing to a file:

```
File.open(filename) do |txt|
  puts"Here's your file: #{filename}"
  puts txt.read()
end
```

And:

```
File.open(file_again) do |txt_again|
  puts txt_again.read()
end
```

---

Another possible cause for what you are seeing is that the file you are listing is actually the output of the `ri` command you entered, and you're really just reading and printing that repeatedly.

Comment: I use CNTRL+D because it's the standard method to close/exit command-line "gets" loops. Enter/Return aren't guaranteed to do anything.

Comment: Hey thanks for all the advice, after some investigation and attempting to uninstall/re-install ruby, I discovered that somehow the text file was overwritten somehow with the ri output.  I feel really dumb for not checking that, but thanks for the help.  Also thank you for the code advice.